# How does the result filter work in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Can someone explain the difference between the Action Filter and the Result Filter in ASP.NET Core MVC? I really didn't get it reading the documentation. What exactly is the result execution that we see in the diagram here (gray box on the very bottom): [image]

In the documentation it says that

> *Action filters* can *change the result* returned from the action.

So if it already changes the result why do we need an Result filter?

Answer (score 4):

According to Microsoft Docs:

> Action filters:
>
> - **Run code immediately before and after an action method is called**.
> - Can change the arguments passed into an action.
> - Can change the result returned from the action.
> - Are not supported in Razor Pages.

But, the `ResultFilter`s have a bit difference in executaion:

> Result filters run code immediately before and after the execution of action results. **They run only when the action method has executed successfully.** They are useful for logic that must surround view or formatter execution.

Consider you want to return an API response to the client for a `User` model with lots of properties. You can simply create a response based on the API model contract like this:

```
public class UserDetailFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
{
        public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if (result?.Value is UserResponse value)
            result.Value = new
            {
                Id = value.Id,
                Username = value.Username,
                Fullname = value.Fullname,
                Mobile = value.Mobile,
                Email = value.Email,
                UpdatedAt = value.UpdatedAt
            };
        await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you could to that in the OnActionExecuted method. You can also access the context.Result from there. So basically I would ResultFilter just to make sure that an exception was not raised and I have a valid result?