# Return Generic response object/json for all the controllers methods using .NetCore middleware

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.reflection

My controller:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet("/getResponse/{userId}")]
  public async Task<MyResponse> GetResponseAsync(long userId)
  {
     return await _myService.GetResponseAsync(userId);
  }
  [HttpGet("/getUser/{userId}")]
  public async Task<MyUser> GetUserAsync(long userId)
  {
     return await _myService.GetUserAsync(userId);
  }
}
```

though my controller returns an object of `MyResponse` or MyUser class, I want to return a custom generic response object i.e.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
  public object Response { get; set; }
  public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
  public IList<string> Errors { get; set; }
  public ApiResponse(object response, bool success, IList<string> errors = null)
  {
     this.Response = response;
     this.IsSuccess = success;
     this.Errors = errors;
  }
    
  public ApiResponse()
  {
  }
}
```

I tried to use IActionFilter's OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) to read the response object, but I don't see any response of MyUser or MyResponse object in the body when i debug for variable a.

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            ApiResponse _response = new ApiResponse();
            var httpResponse = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (httpResponse != null)
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                   var a = httpResponse.Body;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to read the type of object and assign that particular object to the ApiResponse.response proeperty?

Comment: What you ask is what IActionResult already does. There's even a W3C standard for bad request problem responses. It's already used to automatically send 400 responses for validation failures

Comment: I agree with @PanagiotisKanavos that what you want to do does not seem a good idea (at least when not being aware of wider context), because there are some standards and out of the box solutions for that. But if you really need to provide a response in a form of such a custom envelope (for example in order to comply with some other system interface) you can check my answer about MVC filters.

Comment: @KonradKacperczyk as suggested by you, I was trying to implement the IActionResult interface and use it as a FilterAttribute on top of my controller class. However it throws an error saying that my filterattribute class is unable to cast to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterMetadata. Am I missing something?

Comment: @KonradKacperczyk I created MyFilterAttribute class which inherits from IActionResult and added that class as a middleware via the program.cs using the following code--> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyFilterAttribute>();

Comment: You've got interfaces wrong - if you want to use ```ActionFilter``` as class attribute it is enough to make a class that implements ```ActionFilterAttribute``` and just use this attribute on a controller, so: 

```public class SampleFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
        }
    }``` and then apply ```[SampleFilter]``` on your controller.

Comment: @KonradKacperczyk that really helped, thanks. However I have a weird doubt, I see that the onActionExecuted has void returntype. So even if I create a customresponse object like mentioned in my OP (ApiResponse), how will I assign it to the Httcontext.Response since it is a readonly property. My ultimate response should be an object of  ApiResponse i.e. {Response: { id: 1, property1:somedata}, Error: null, IsSucess:true}

Comment: @KonradKacperczyk I figured it out, I should be using context.Result instead of httpconext.response. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few types of MVC filters, and IActionFilter is not the best tool for this job. What you want is ResultFilter.

Please take a look at official documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0 for more details.

An answer provided here may also be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64725441/2895299

However, it is going to work with your filter implementation as well, you're just looking for a response object in wrong place. Your object is going to be accessible under:

```
context.Result
```

Response in *HttpContext* object is going to be accessible later, not at filter stage of MVC pipeline. Please observe, that *context.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted* is equal to false.

What is more, response / request available in *HttpContext* is not going to be typed (binded to model), it would be for example in JSON format like *{"userId": "123", "username": "Foo" }*

Comment: ASP.NET Core already provides a standards-based type that does exactly what the OP wants and is used automatically on many failures. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) show how to use filters to customize it even further, eg returning specific contents for specific exceptions

Comment: I agree with you, I also agree with the answer you provided about ```application/problem+json``` - in general it is a good way to go - but from what I understood, the question asked covers a little bit more than just exception handling. If for some reason Shekar.gvr wants to return a custom envelope it can be done using custom filters.

Comment: @KonradKacperczyk you are right , I am not too focused on exception handling. And wouldn't want to use this generic API response in case of exception. But my requirement is more focused on when the API call is a success, then the response object schema has to be the same for all the endpoints, and within the response object there can be differnt class objects.

Answer (score 1):

There's already [IETF RFC 7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807) for HTTP API problem responses, with its own content type, `application/problem+json`. ASP.NET Core uses it to [return automatic model validation failure responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation-failure-error-response).

It's a bad idea to use a custom format when there's a standard that's actually used by clients and libraries.

Example responses can be :

```
   HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
   Content-Type: application/problem+json
   Content-Language: en

   {
    "type": "https://example.com/probs/out-of-credit",
    "title": "You do not have enough credit.",
    "detail": "Your current balance is 30, but that costs 50.",
    "instance": "/account/12345/msgs/abc",
    "balance": 30,
    "accounts": ["/account/12345",
                 "/account/67890"]
   }
```

Or

```
   HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
   Content-Type: application/problem+json
   Content-Language: en

   {
   "type": "https://example.net/validation-error",
   "title": "Your request parameters didn't validate.",
   "invalid-params": [ {
                         "name": "age",
                         "reason": "must be a positive integer"
                       },
                       {
                         "name": "color",
                         "reason": "must be 'green', 'red' or 'blue'"}
                     ]
   }
```

ASP.NET Core uses the [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and the more specific [ValidationProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-6.0) classes to report errors.

It's possible to send a Problem or ValidationProblem response using the [Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-6.0) or [ValidationProblem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem?view=aspnetcore-6.0) functions, eg:

```
var details=new ValidationProblemDetails(someDictionary);
return ValidationProblem(details);
```

The [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0) article shows how ASP.NET Core can be configured to returns customized ProblemDetails for specific exceptions

Comment: I understand that using IActionFilter works, is there a way to write a custom middleware to implement the same thing? Because that way we can avoid decorating the controller with the [FilterAttribute]

Answer (score 0):

A consistent response from endpoints is very much recommended, as it provides significant help on the consumer side.

The response has two states

- OnSuccess
- OnError

We need to standardize both states so consumers can easily predict responses from the endpoint. It also aids in reducing breaking changes when modifying existing code.

For asp.net core middleware is the best option to implement the generic responses for the existing application. Below is the step-by-step guide for the implementation of the solution.

1- Create a generic response DTO

```
public class ResponseModel<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

2- Create middleware to handle the **OnSuccess** state.

```
public class ResponseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = responseBody;

            await _next(context);

            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var responseBodyContent = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 200 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
            {
                // Deserialize the original response content
                var originalResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBodyContent);

                // Wrap the response in ResponseModel<T>
                var genericResponse = new ResponseModel<object>
                {
                    Success = true,
                    Data = originalResponse,
                    ErrorMessage = null // No error message if successful
                };

                // Serialize the ResponseModel<T> to the response body
                var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(genericResponse);
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the response status code is not 200, return the original response content
                await responseBody.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3- Register middleware in `statup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // ...

        // Add the ResponseMiddleware to the request pipeline
        app.UseMiddleware<ResponseMiddleware>();

        // ...
    }
}
```

4- Handle exceptions **OnError** state

```
public class ResponseExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // Wrap the exception in ResponseModel<T>
        var genericResponse = new ResponseModel<object>
        {
            Success = false,
            Data = null, // No data if an exception occurred
            ErrorMessage = context.Exception.Message // Set the error message from the exception
        };

        context.Result = new ObjectResult(genericResponse)
        {
            StatusCode = 500 // You can customize the error status code
        };
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...

        services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            // Add the ResponseExceptionFilter as a global exception filter
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ResponseExceptionFilter));
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```